# Unity access Label in GUI?

Tags: c#, unity

There is a quick and dirty appreoch to creating text boxes:

```
void OnGUI(){
    GUILayout.Label("Text 1");
}
```

It works well. But, since the Label method returns `void`, how do I access this later on?

Let's say I want to access the text later to change the score?

```
someField = GUILayout.Label("Text 1");
```

Is not going to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a Label, the only way would be to keep your text in a string variable and manually handle all key events by changing the string variable accordingly. Clearly, this is far from ideal.

If you want a quick and dirty textbox, you should use [TextField](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.TextField.html), which does all of the hard work for you.

Of course, this assumes you're sticking with the classic UI system, which your code snippet suggests. If you're using the new UI system, add an [Input Field](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html) to a [Text](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Text.html) control.